# Positioning of Elements Off

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am coding a website for a history class. The background of the site is a map of Europe, and on the map are numbers. The goal of the site is to have these numbers positioned on a specific country, so that when the user hovers over a number, it displays that countries dialect and religion. My problem being that when I open the website on another computer, all of the numbers are off and not positioned on their correct country. Ive tried using percentages to position them to no avail. I'm sure it's an amateur mistake, but I cant seem to find the solution and I need to present the site in school tommorow. If anyone can think of a solution, it would be greatly appreciated! I've posted the code for one of the pages below.

**EDIT**Here is a link to a screenshot of the site, with the 1 being in the correct position, however it shifts when opened on another PC. https://gyazo.com/9b4bc7d51178d45c74130f7ea4b0b9e2

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Celtic Region</title>
    <style>
        div {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            }
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            background-color: ffffcc;
            }
        .header {
            width: 100%;
            height: 8%;
            font-size: 50px;
            font-family: verdana;
            background-color: 659DBD;
            text-align: center;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px 6px black;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
            color: white;
            }
        .navbar {
            width: 100%;
            height: 5%;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: 659DBD;
            font-family: verdana;
            font-size: 25px;
            padding-top: 5px;
            box-shadow: 8px 8px 10px gray;
            }
        .navbar a:link {
            text-decoration: none;
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-right: 15px;
            padding-top: 3px;
            padding-bottom: 3px;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 10px;
            text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px gray;
            }
        .navbar a:visited {
            color: white;
            }
        .navbar a:hover {
            background-color: gray;
            visibility: visible;
            }
        .map {
            background: url(BlankMap.png) no-repeat 50% 0;
            }
        .irishGaelic {
            font-family: verdana;
            font-size: 30px;
            left: 360px;
            top: 470px;
            position: absolute;
            }
        .irishGaelic:hover .popupText {
            visibility: visible;
            }
        .popupText {
            visibility: hidden;
            font-size: 15px;
            position: static;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 6px;
            padding: 5px;
            }
        .scotsGaelic {
            font-family: verdana;
            font-size: 30px;
            left: 240px;
            top: 600px;
            position: absolute;
            }
        .scotsGaelic:hover .popupText {
            visibility: visible;
            }
        .welsh {
            font-family: verdana;
            font-size: 30px;
            top: 610px;
            left: 370px;
            position: absolute;
            }
        .welsh:hover .popupText {
            visibility: visible;
            }
        .breton {
            font-family: verdana;
            font-size: 30px;
            left: 350px;
            top: 760px;
            position: absolute;
            }
        .breton:hover .popupText {
            visibility: visible;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        Western Europe Ethno Linguistic Map
    </div>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="CelticRegion.html">Celtic Region</a>
        <a href="GermanicRegion.html">Germanic Region</a>
        <a href="RomanceRegion.html">Romance Region</a>
    </div>

    <div class="map">
        <img src="BlankMap.png" alt="Western Europe">
        <div class="irishGaelic">1
            <div class="popupText">
                Dialect: Irish-Gaelic<br>
                Religion: Catholic
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="scotsGaelic">2
            <div class="popupText">
                Dialect: Scots-Gaelic<br>
                Religion: Protestant
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="welsh">3
            <div class="popupText">
                Dialect: Welsh<br>
                Religion: Protestant
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="breton">4
            <div class="popupText">
                Dialect: Breton<br>
                Religion: Protestant
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: Do you have an external URL to the map? It's a bit hard to visualize what you mean, given there's no map to on our end.

Comment: I took a screenshot, the 1 is in it's correct position, however when opened on another computer it changes positions. The link is https://gyazo.com/9b4bc7d51178d45c74130f7ea4b0b9e2